# Python - How do I animate my scatterplot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

This is my script so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
t=0
r=3.0
n=0
A=[]
for x in range(10):
  for y in range(10):
    A.append([random.uniform(0,1),random.uniform(0,1)])
for m in range(len(A)):
  plt.plot(A[m][0],A[m][1], "x", color="blue")
plt.show()
while n<=100:
  for m in range(len(A)):
    A[m][0]=r*A[m][0]*(1-A[m][0])
    A[m][1]=r*A[m][1]*(1-A[m][1])
  for m in range(len(A)):
    plt.plot(A[m][0],A[m][1], "x", color="blue")
  plt.show()
  n+=1
```

What I want to do now is animate it, so that I don't have to close the plot each time it for python to recalculate an show me the next image. Instead, it should show me a new plot every say 5s. What's the best way for me to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `plt.ion()` to enable interactive plotting (doesn't make the execution stop when a plot-window is opened) and then use `plt.clf()` to clear the plot.

A working sample is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()

import random
t=0
r=3.0
n=0
A=[]
for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        A.append([random.uniform(0,1),random.uniform(0,1)])

for m in range(len(A)):
    plt.plot(A[m][0],A[m][1], "x", color="blue")
    plt.draw()
plt.pause(1)

while n<=100:
    for m in range(len(A)):
        A[m][0]=r*A[m][0]*(1-A[m][0])
        A[m][1]=r*A[m][1]*(1-A[m][1])
    for m in range(len(A)):
        plt.plot(A[m][0],A[m][1], "x", color="blue")
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(1)
    plt.clf()
```

You must use `plt.draw()` to force the GUI to update immediately and `plt.pause(t)` to break for t seconds. Actually, I'm not quite sure how you want to treat the two parts of your script (the two loops containing plot-commands) in terms of animation, but hopefully, my code will guide you the right way.

**Remarks**

First, I'd recommend to stick to some conventions when coding python. Use 4-space indentation, this makes your code much more readable. Second, I'd recommend using numpy for arrays. You import it but you don't use it. This makes your code definitely faster.
Third and last, are you aware of the signature `plot(x,y,"bx")` for matplotlib? I think it's really convenient.

Comment: Thanks! A couple of changes, and it does exactly what I want it to. And thanks too for the tips, numpy is still left over from an earlier version, when I was working with numpy.linspace, I forgot to delete the import numpy part.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `matplotlib.animation` package:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random

t=0
r=3.0
n=0
A=[]

for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        A.append([random.uniform(0,1),random.uniform(0,1)])
A = np.array(A).transpose()

fig = plt.figure()
line, = plt.plot(A[0],A[1], "x", color="blue")

def update():
    for i in range(100):
        A[0], A[1] = r*A[0]*(1-A[0]), r*A[1]*(1-A[1])
        yield A

def draw(data):
    line.set_xdata(data[0])
    line.set_ydata(data[1])
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, draw, update, interval=1000, blit=False)

plt.show()
```

The `update` function is a generator, which yields the data for subsequent steps, while `draw` is a function that updates the plot data and returns it.

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that the animation module keeps a copy of the results that get pulled off `update` which may cause memory issues if your frames are huge.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the object oriented interface of matplotlib, nicely summarized in the [artist tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html#artist-tutorial).

With this, you get finer control over the figure behaviour and can simply redraw the plot within your loop:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from time import sleep
t=0
r=3.0
n=0
A=[]
for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        A.append([random.uniform(0,1),random.uniform(0,1)])
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for m in range(len(A)):
    ax.plot(A[m][0],A[m][1], "x", color="blue")
fig.show()
sleep(1)
while n<=100:
    for m in range(len(A)):
        A[m][0]=r*A[m][0]*(1-A[m][0])
        A[m][1]=r*A[m][1]*(1-A[m][1])
    ax.clear()
    for m in range(len(A)):
        ax.plot(A[m][0],A[m][1], "x", color="blue")
    fig.canvas.draw()
    sleep(1)
    n+=1
```

Key changes from your script are using `fig.show` instead of `plt.show` and updating the figure with `fig.canvas.draw` after changing the data.